# Why the sentence "The expression can be used only as the left-hand operand of a member function call" in [expr.ref]p(6.3.2)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, member-functions, function-call

[[expr.ref]p(6.3.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#6.3.2):

> Otherwise, if `E1.E2` refers to a non-static member function and the
>   type of `E2` is “function of parameter-type-list *cv*
>   *ref-qualifier*<sub>*opt*</sub> returning T”, then `E1.E2` is a prvalue. The expression designates a non-static member function. **The
>   expression can be used only as the left-hand operand of a member
>   function call ([class.mfct])**. [ Note: Any redundant set of
>   parentheses surrounding the expression is ignored ([expr.prim.paren]).
>   — end note ] The type of `E1.E2` is “function of parameter-type-list
>   *cv* returning `T`”.

For example the second statement in `main` below doesn't compile, probably because of the highlighted sentence above. But why is the language set up to work this way?

```
#include<iostream>
void g();
struct S { void f(); };
S s;

int main(){
    std::cout << "decltype(g) == void() ? " << std::is_same<decltype(g), void()>::value << '\n';            // Ok
    std::cout << "decltype(s.f) == void() ? " << std::is_same<decltype(s.f), void()>::value << '\n';        // Doesn't compile probably because of the sentence hihlighted above in [expr.ref]p(6.3.2).
}
```

Comment: "*But why is the language set up to work this way?*" Exactly what would it be otherwise? `S::f` is not a `void()` function; it's a member function.

Comment: What do you expect `s.f` to mean, were it valid?

Comment: @NicolBolas [\[dcl.type.decltype\]p(1.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#decltype-1.3) tells exaclty what I would expect for the type to be.

Comment: If you expect `decltype(s.f)` to be the same as `void()`, would you also expect `sizeof(s.f) == sizeof(void())`? Would you expect `auto h = s.f; h();` to work? There's not enough space in a plain function pointer to store information sufficient to make `s.f()` call later.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ["The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such types, or to a glvalue that designates a bit-field."](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1.sentence-3)

Comment: I think I would expect `decltype(s.f)` to *not* be the same as `void()`, but that the above code would compile and print `false`...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Well, [\[dcl.type.decltype\]p(1.3)] (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#decltype-1.3) says that `decltype(s.f) == void()` were not for the statement highlighted above, disallowing the use of `s.f` other than when calling a member function `f`.

Comment: @Belloc: Were it not for the statement highlighted, "type of the entity named" would not be `void()`.  Maybe "non-static member function of type `struct S` taking no explicit parameters and returning `void`".  Maybe some variant with "and bound".  (But not "and bound to `s`", because the identity of an object instance is value information not type information)

Comment: I would expect `decltype(s.f)` to be some kind of member function type (perhaps something morally equivalent to `void (S::&)()` if that existed), not a function type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `E1.E2`, you are not talking about a general property of the type of thing that `E1` is. You're asking to access a thing within the *object* designated by `E1`, where the name of the thing to be accessed is `E2`. If `E2` is static, it accesses the class static thing; if `E2` is non-static, then it accesses the member thing *specific to that object*. That's important.

Member variables become the subobject. If your class `S` had a non-static data member `int i;`, `s.i` is a reference to an `int`. That reference, from the stand point of an `int&`, behaves no differently from any other `int&`.

Let me say that more clearly: any `int*` or `int&` can point to/reference an `int` which is a complete object or an `int` which is a subobject of some other object. The single construct `int&` can serve double-duty in this way.<sup>*</sup>

Given that understanding of `s.i`, what would be the presumed meaning of `s.f`? Well, it should be similar, right? `s.f` would be some kind of thing that, when called with `params`, will be the equivalent of doing `s.f(params)`.

But that is not a thing which exists in C++.

There is no language construct in C++ which can represent that meaning of `s.f`. Such a construct would need to store a reference to `s` as well as the member `S::f`.

A function pointer can't do that. Function pointers need to be able to be pointer-interconvertible with `void*`<sup>**</sup>. But such an `s.f` would need to store the member `S::f` as well as a reference to `s` itself. So by definition, it'll have to be bigger than a `void*`.

A member pointer can't do that either. Member pointers explicitly don't carry their `this` object along with them (that's kind of the point); you must provide them at call-time using the specific member pointer call syntax `.*` or `.->`.

Oh, there are ways to encode this within the language: lambdas, `std::bind`, etc. But there is no language-level construct which has this precise meaning.

Because C++ is asymmetric in this way, where `s.i` has an encodable meaning but not `s.f`, C++ makes the unencodable one illegal.

You may ask why such a construct doesn't simply get built. It's not really that important. The language works perfectly fine as is, and due to the complexity of what an `s.f` would need to be, it's probably best to make you use a lambda (for which admittedly there should be ways to make it shorter to write such things) if that's what you want.

And if you want a naked `s.f` to be equivalent to `S::f` (ie: designates the member function), that doesn't really work either. First, `S::f` doesn't have a type either; the only thing you can do with such a prvalue is convert it to a pointer to a member. Second, a member function pointer doesn't know what object it came from, so in order to use one to call the member, you need to give it `s`. Therefore, in a call expression, `s` would have to appear twice. Which is really silly.

<sup>*</sup>: there are things you can *do* to complete objects that you cannot do to subobjects. But those provoke UB because they're not detectable by the compiler, because an `int*` doesn't say if it comes from a subobject or not. Which is the main point; nobody can tell the difference.

<sup>**</sup>: the standard does not require this, but the standard cannot do something which out-right makes such an implementation *impossible*. Most implementations provide this functionality, and basically any DLL/SO loading code relies on it. Oh, and it would also be completely incompatible with C, which makes it a non-starter.

Comment: [\[dcl.type.decltype\]p(1.3)(http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#decltype-1.3) says that `decltype(s.f) == void()`, the same way `decltype(g) == void()` in the example. I'm sorry but I can't be more objective than this. AFAICT, the only reason this code doesn't compile is because of the alluded statement in [expr.ref]p(6.3.2).

Comment: @Belloc: Where does it say that? It says "type of the entity named by e.". Well, `s.f` names "a non-static member function". And the type of that non-static member function is not `void()`; that's not how typing works with non-static members.

Comment: I finally got what you're trying to tell me. I was wrong, `decltype(s.f)` would not be equal to `void()`, even if we assumed that the expression `decltype(s.f)` were well-formed. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolBolas: `void()` **is** the type of that (defective) expression.

Comment: @curiousguy: As a matter of interest, `memcpy` between trivially copyable objects doesn't work if one of them is a base class subobject. This is due to EBO; an empty object type still has a non-zero `sizeof`, but if the base class is subject to EBO, it may overlap with other subobjects. So such copies are forbidden, even though they would be *generally* allowed with that type. Also, C++20's `[[no_unique_address]]` [expands this restriction](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#3) to properly designated member subobjects too.

Comment: @NicolBolas So you proved that some trivial subobjects cannot have their (address,size) information used as if they were complete objects: those that are base classes and more recently those you designated as not being treatable as complete objects. As `memcpy` is used to copy information, there is no reason (outside generic code maybe) to ever do a bitwise copy a the non empty representation of information free object, which would be inherently less efficient then copying its (zero) members.

Comment: My Q: "what guarantees exist for complete objects don't exist for subobjects" was in the context of "_because an int* doesn't say if it comes from a subobject or not._". Obviously a `int` subobject cannot be a base class; and anything containing one isn't empty and I don't see how integers could overlap in practice.

Comment: @curiousguy: The point of the footnote is to not leave the reader with the impression that pointers/references to complete objects and subobjects behave 100% identically in all cases. It's not intended to be a declaration that `int*/&` *specifically* will behave differently in some cases, merely preventing the reader from having an incorrect idea about C++ in general. That's why it's a *footnote* and not inline text. So it's best to just treat the statement as it is intended and move on.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm sorry I misinterpreted the scope of the footnote. We can agree to agree!

Answer (score 1):

The `stat_result.st_mtime` syntax was inherited from C, where it always has a value (more particularly, an lvalue).  It is therefore **syntactically** an expression even in the case of a method call, but it has no value because it is evaluated in concert with its associated call expression.

It is (as you quoted) given the **type** of the member function so as to satisfy the [requirement](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6) that a function be called via an expression of the correct type.  It would, however, be **misleading** to define `decltype` for it since it cannot be a *full-expression* (as is [every unevaluated operand](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5.1)) and common expression SFINAE with `decltype` would not prevent a hard error from the guarded instantiation.

Note that a non-static member function [*can* be named](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#expr.context-1.note-1) in an unevaluated operand, but that allows `S::f` (or just `f` within the class, although that is arguably [rewritten](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.mfct.non-static-3.sentence-1) to be `(*this).f` in a member function), not `s.f`.  That expression [has the same type](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#17.note-1) but is itself restricted (to appearing with `&` to form a pointer to member [function]) for the same reason: if it were to be used otherwise, it would be usable as a normal [function] pointer, which is impossible.

Comment: I'm really interested in understanding what you wrote above. But your answer is too terse for my knowledge. Could you be so kind to rewrite it in more simple terms?

Comment: @WaldB: I wouldn’t call this *terse*—could you say what it is that you don’t understand?

Comment: You can't form a pointer to member with `&f` even inside the class.  It definitely means `this->f` which as we've already seen (the topic of the whole question) cannot be used in any way except a function call.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There’s some confusion on this subject, I think—note that compilers [reject](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0Q3vbaBgQdbQKSGU) a use of a non-static member function’s name even in a context where `this` is not allowed, despite the fact that no implicit `(*this).` should be added there.

Comment: @DavisHerring: The compiler is correct to generate errors in your link: you can only form a pointer-to-member by using a qualified name.  And there is no such thing as a member function type, only a pointer-to-member type so `decltype(S::f)` is also illegal but `decltype(&S::f)` is allowed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Nothing tries to make a pointer-to-member here: (as I linked in the answer) member functions have [normal function types](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#17.note-1).

Comment: Yeah.... that note looks like a wording defect.  Inspecting the type of a member function (qualified name) may result in a normal function type (useful for template meta-programming), but that's a fiction created by the inspection operation; the member function does not actually conform to that type in any type theory sense.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There are even types like `int() const` for const-`this` member functions.  They’re certainly not an accident, even though they are extremely strange.